# Read all sale.order objects on draft state from a custom module - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

How can I read from a related field, all sale.order objects which are on 'draft' state?

I've tried this:

```
class account_budget_bsi(models.Model):

    _name = 'account.budget.bsi'

    _inherit = ['crossovered.budget', 'sale.order', 'stock.location', 'stock.move', 'purchase.order']

    sale_order = fields.Many2one('sale.order')
    sales_bsi = fields.Many2one('sale.order' , related="sale_order.state.draft", string="Sales Planned")
```

But it's not working as it seems.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

I mean, the issue is that all the sale orders must be on 'draft' state, I know that maybe the Many2one related field isn't working because 'state' is a Selection one, but can't figure out how to load it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not what related fields are for. You should achieve this with a computed field somehow like this:

```
sales_bsi =  fields.One2many('sale.order',
             compute="_compute_sales_bsi")

@api.one
def _compute_sales_bsi(self):
    self.sales_bsi = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '=', 'draft')])
```

What this does is that it searches the `sale.order` model for records that are in draft state, and adds them to the field `sales_bsi`. If I understand right that is what you want to achieve.

Comment: It's hard to say based on the original question. If @NeoVe wants to automatically choose all `draft` sales orders and assign them to the `account.budget.bsi` record, then your answer would be best. If they want to only show the list of all `draft` sales orders and choose one, my answer would be more appropriate.

Comment: Indeed, the question was somewhat ambigious. I hope he'll clear up about that.

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much, yes, I want to automatically choose all 'draft' sales orders and assign them to 'account.budget.bsi' object

Comment: Yes, I'm trying but when I try to create a new budget it throws: 'ValueError: Wrong value for account.budget.bsi.state: u'draft''

Comment: That is probably a problem unrelated to the one that the question was about.

Answer (score 1):

**How to Use `related`**

Related is only for loading the actual value of another object's field. The field must be the same type as the field you're making the relation to.

Example:

```
sales_state = fields.Selection(related='sales_order.state')
```

Once you choose a `sales_order`, the `sales_state` field would automatically load the related `state` of the `sales_order`.

**How to Restrict Selection**

Now, as for what you're actually trying to do. Are you wanting to only allow the `sales_order` field to select a Sales Order that is in the Draft state? If so, you want to use `domain`.

```
sales_order = fields.Many2one('sale.order', domain=[('state', '=', 'draft')])
```

[Read up on domain here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#domains)

**Follow-up Question**

```
_inherit = ['crossovered.budget', 'sale.order', 'stock.location', 'stock.move', 'purchase.order']
```

Why are you inheriting from so much? Surely there is no need to inherit all of these.

Comment: I have to inherit these because there aother matters i have to address with this class, anyways, I'm going to try and maybe open a new question,Thank You very much!